# How to call vim script in C language

Tags: vim

## what's my goal:

i want a program to get session.vim and viminfo.info file for each file being edited by vim,
and scp these file to another pc, then i can continue the work on another pc.

### problems:

- maybe the file isn't saved.

  - should save the file before the program generate the session.vim.
- how get the absolute path of the file.

  - i just can get the file name using ps -ef | grep vim.
  - getcwd() can get the current working derectory.but, i can't push it to my program written by C.

Here is my solution, but it doesn't work, maybe you get a better solution, i need your help.

kill all vim process, and get session.vim and viminfo.info for each file. 
in my C code:

```
system(kill -9 pid);//pid is the pid of vim process.
```

in my .vimrc file:

```
autocmd VimEnter * let s:this_session='.'.expand('%:t').'.vim'
autocmd VimLeave * if v:dying | call Somefunc() | endif
function! Somefunc()
    silent! wa
    execute 'mksession! '.fnameescape(s:this_session)
endfunction
```

it does not work.

do i make myself clear? i'm not good at english.

i'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Maybe you should describe in more details what you want to achieve because it is a bit fuzzy right now.

Comment: But why? Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thank you a lot, i have rewrite my question.=)

Answer (score 1):

`man kill` says this:

> SIGKILL      9    kill (cannot be caught or ignored)

With the `-9` argument, Vim (as well as any other process) has no chance to react to the signal; the process will be forcibly terminated. Try sending the default `SIGTERM (15)` by omitting the `-9` argument. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/107543/bash-man-page-kill-pid-vs-kill-9-pid) for more information.